# dom-bind error: listener method not defined

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using polymer 1.0 and having a problem in registering methods and calling them. It works fine in Chrome but in Firefox I'm getting this error message:

```
[dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `_onCircleClick` not defined
```

This part of code below included inside other polymer element.

```
<template id="main" is="dom-bind">
  <neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="0">
    <main-page on-circle-click="_onCircleClick"></main-page>
    <detail-page on-click="_onPageClick"></detail-page>
  </neon-animated-pages>
</template>
<script>
  var template = document.querySelector('#main');

  template._onCircleClick = function (event) {
    this.$.pages.selected = 1;
  };

  template._onPageClick = function (event) {
    this.$.pages.selected = 0;
  };
</script>
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work in Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading the webcomponents.js polyfill ?

Comment: yes, I'm loading `<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>`

but it didn't help

Comment: Side note: docs recommend using `on-tap` rather than `on-click`: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#gestures

Comment: Does it work if you replace `on-circle-click` with `on-click`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a custom tag, I think you should not be using dom-bind.

Instead of using `template._onCircleClick = function()`
try `_onCircleClick: function()`

```
(function(){
        Polymer({
            is: "tag-name",
            properties: {
            },
            _onCircleClick: function() {
                this.$.pages.selected = 1;
            },
        });
    })();
```